# How to configure Text value in flutter based on conditions?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

I fetching the below single character code from the server like 'M', 'T' or 'B', etc in flutter application

```
M = Manual
T = Trial
B = Baking
N = N/A
S = Source
O = Other Source
```

Now there is only `Text()` element configured in a listview which has to represent the value like 'Manual','Trial'or 'Baking' etc, based on the code retrieved.

I know how to implement the ternary operator , if there was only 2 elements to be choosen from.
But in this case there are 6 options and only one was to be represented.

How should I configure this in flutter listview builder??

```
 child:Text('value to be represented here')
```

I am not able to understand how the 'if-else if - else' will work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function like:

```
// The code represents the single character code
String getNameFromCode(String code){
    switch(code){
        case 'M': return 'Manual';
        case 'T': return 'Trial';
        case 'B': return 'Baking';
        case 'N': return 'N/A';
        case 'S': return 'Source';
        case 'O': return 'Other Source';
    }
}
```

Use that function as an input to text widget:

```
Text(getNameFromCode(getDataFromServer()))
```

I assume you need to output one value; I don't know why you do need a `ListView`.

For a list of such codes:

```
List<String> codes = getDataFromServer()
ListView.builder(
  itemCount:
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i){
    return Text(getNameFromCode(codes[i]));
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, String> values = {
    "M": "Manual",
    "T": "Trial",
    "B": "Baking",
    "N": "N/A",
    "S": "Source",
    "O": "Other Source",
  };

  print(values["M"]); // Manual

  print(values["O"]); // Other Source

}
```